# Query to extract data from string

Tags: sql, string, extract

I have a field with the following "formatted" data: "XYZ100320C00027500". In this:

- XYZ - Symbol (up to 6 characters)
- 10 - Year (2 characters)
- 03 - Month (2 characters)
- 20 - Day (2 characters)
- C - Call/Put (C or P)
- 00027 - Strike Dollar (5 characters)
- 500 - Strike Decimal (3 characters)

From this field I need to extract the symbol, date (month/day/year), call/put, strike (strike dollar+strike decimal).  I need to extract these and put them in their own columns in one table.

Any help or direction with how to do this with a sql query would be much appreciated.

Comment: What DB engine do you use?

Comment: I am using sql and I am very new to it.  I really don't know what to try that is why I am asking for any help or direction.

Comment: as mentioned in example,all other fields except Symbol, will contain fixed length values. means will it happen that "Strike dollar" has limit upto 5 char,but it have only as "27" insted of"00027".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work, although it might not be too efficient...

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9b5e1/2)

**MS SQL Server 2012 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE Table1
    (the_string varchar(21))
;

INSERT INTO Table1
    (the_string)
VALUES
    ('XYZ100320C00027500'),
    ('ABCDEF120410C00022540')
;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SET DATEFORMAT ymd
SELECT 

    SUBSTRING(the_string, 0, PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', the_string)) AS [Symbol], 
    CAST( SUBSTRING(the_string, PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', the_string), 2) + '-' + SUBSTRING(the_string, PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', the_string)+2, 2) + '-' + SUBSTRING(the_string, PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', the_string)+4, 2) AS DATE) AS [Date],
    SUBSTRING(the_string, PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', the_string)+6, 1) AS [Call/Put], 
    CAST(SUBSTRING(the_string, PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', the_string)+7, 5) AS FLOAT) + CAST(SUBSTRING(the_string, PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', the_string)+12, 3) AS FLOAT)/1000 AS [Strike]

FROM table1
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9b5e1/2/0)**:

```
| SYMBOL |       DATE | CALL/PUT | STRIKE |
|--------|------------|----------|--------|
|    XYZ | 2010-03-20 |        C |   27.5 |
| ABCDEF | 2012-04-10 |        C |  22.54 |
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for.  Everything works great!  A great learning opportunity.  Thank you.